# Rudin Theorem 3.27

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 3.27 of Rudin's book [*Principles of mathematical analysis*](http://books.google.com/books?id=kwqzPAAACAAJ) at pages 61-62 states that,

Suppose $a_1\ge a_2\ge a_3\ge \cdots \ge 0.$ Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges if and only if the series
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{k}a_{2^{k}}=a_{1}+2a_{2}+4a_{4}+8a_{8}+\cdots$ converges.

I could follow all of the arguments except the the last sentence, which is

By (8) and (9), the sequences $\left\{ s_{n}\right\}$ and $\left\{ t_{k}\right\}$ are either both bounded or both unbounded.

Here (8) and (9) are

(8) For $n<2^k$, $s_n \le t_k$.

(9) For $n>2^k$, $2s_n \ge t_k$.

where 
$s_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$, $t_{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^{i}a_{2^{i}}.$

Why are the two sequences either both bounded or both unbounded? The (8) seems to imply that if $t_k$ converges, then $s_n$ converges. The (9) seems to imply that if $s_n$ converges, then $t_k$ converges. I could not further more arguments to see how the last sentence works.

Thank you for any help.

BTW, for $n=2^k$, it seems like $s_n \le t_k$.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for a more general statement.

Comment: So, it is not like that either $n<2^k$ or $n>2^k$? Even without comparing $n$ and $2^k$, one should be able to get $s_n\le t_k\le 2s_n$? The wiki link of "Cauchy condensation test" is helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Suppose $\{s_n\}$ is bounded, so that $-M \le s_n \le  M$ for some $M > 0$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Choose $n_1$ such that $n_1 < 2^k$.  By $(8)$,

$$-M \le s_{n_1} \le t_k$$

Now choose $n_2$ so that $n_2 > 2^k$.  Then

$$2M \ge 2s_{n_2} \ge t_k$$

Hence, the sequence $\{t_n\}$ is bounded. Use similar reasoning to conclude that if $\{t_n\}$ is bounded, then $\{s_n\}$ is bounded.

Suppose $\{s_n\}$ is unbounded.  Let $M > 0$.  There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n > M$. Choose $k$ such that $2^k > n$.  Then,

$$t_k \ge s_n > M$$

so $\{t_n\}$ is unbounded.  The converse ($\{t_n\}$  unbounded $\implies$ $\{s_n\}$ unbounded) is similar.

Answer (score 3):

[I do not understand your confusion, so I'd just write out what appears obvious, using the word bounded/unbounded instead of converge (which we don't care as yet)]

If $s_n$ is unbounded, then by (8), $t_k$ is unbounded. If $t_k$ is unbounded, then by (9), $s_n$ is unbounded.

If $s_n$ is bounded, then by (9), $t_k$ is bounded. If $t_k$ is bounded, then by (8), $s_n$ is bounded.

Comment: So, one should use both cases of $n<2^k$ and $n>2^k$? I thought that each case should be considered separately. Thank you!

Comment: @SangcheolChoi, if $\{t_k\}$ is bounded, then $\{t_k\} \leq M$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. So $n \lt 2^k$ really means $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.