# Is this a typo? Baby Rudin Theorem 3.27 is not proved correctly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This has been referred to as the Cauchy condensation test.

He only shows the partial sum sequence is bounded not convergent. To do the latter, must show that for $n>N$ the partial sums are within $\epsilon$ of the limit for any $\epsilon > 0$. The sums have room to move around in between $S$ and $2S$ as stated in the book.

Comment: The post is not self-contained. Please consider adding the proof in the post. (FYI: There's another question on this Theorem: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273091/rudin-theorem-3-27))

Comment: Without having had a look at the book, is Rudin maybe implicitly using the fact that increasing sequences converge if they are bounded?

Comment: It is stated and proved correctly in the first edition. As noted there, it suffices to show boundedness, since the terms are non-negative.

Comment: @Bananach: It’s explicit, at least in the first edition.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the helpful comments, boundness is implied by 3.24.  Case closed.  I spent over an hour after missing this little detail.  thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your question, I missed this also :)